# WCF: Cannot find the X.509 certificate

Tags: wcf, wcfserviceclient

Error when browsing Outlook.svc from IIS.
Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindBySubjectName', FindValue ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your WCF service uses a certificate to secure communication, it is usually based on the transport layer or the message layer to encrypt and sign messages.
This makes it necessary to configure a certificate for the service when hosting the WCF service in IIS.
Certificates are usually stored in the certificate Store of windows computers and are divided into current users and local machines.
You can access it using the following shell commands.

> Current User Store: Certmgr.msc
>   Local Machine Store: Certlm.msc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/local-machine-and-current-user-certificate-stores
The error details mainly indicate that there isn’t a specific certificate that meets the search condition in the Local Machine certificate store.
To solve the problem, we could specify another certificate or change the security mode of the WCF service.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.